# How can I fill public variables in a class when I call new instance of it?

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following class:

```
public class Engin
{
   public string ConnictionString;
   public string database;

    public DataTable Selecting_DT(string TableName)
    {
        DataTable functionReturnValue = null;
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnictionString);
        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [" + TableName + "]", sqlCon);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
            da.Fill(dt);
            functionReturnValue = dt;
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
            return functionReturnValue;
        }
        sqlCon.Close();
        return functionReturnValue;
    }
 }
```

When I call this class I write:

```
    public Engin myclass = new Engin();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       myclass.ConnictionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MY_Table;Integrated Security=True";
       DataTable dt = myclass.Selecting_DT("Customer");
    }
```

The question is - if I have 1000 form and I need to call myclass in all these forms
how can I shorten my code so that I can call new instance of myclass without setting ConnectionString all 1000 times?

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but wouldn't you just pass the string in the constructor and have your class assign the string to the Datasource?

Answer (score 2):

Do it in the constructor of your class :

```
public Engin()
{
    this.ConnictionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MY_Table;Integrated Security=True";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the property in the Engin construtor

```
public Engin()
{    
    ConnictionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MY_Table;Integrated Security=True";    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hard-code it:

```
public class Engin
{
    public string ConnictionString = "Data Source=...";
    public string database;
// [cut], usage:    
public Engin myclass = new Engin();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // conn string already set
    DataTable dt = myclass.Selecting_DT("Customer");
}
```

Or put it in the constructor (same result as above if you have only one ctor)

```
public class Engin
{
    public string ConnictionString = "Data Source=...";

    public Engin()
    {
        this.ConnictionString = "Data Source=...";
    }
// [cut], usage:    
public Engin myclass = new Engin();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // conn string also already set
    DataTable dt = myclass.Selecting_DT("Customer");
}
```

Or, you can write an initializer:

```
public class Engin
{
    public string ConnictionString;
    public string database;

    public void InitConnString()
    {
        this.ConnictionString = "Data Source=...";
    }
// [cut], usage:    
public Engin myclass = new Engin();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myclass.InitConnString();
   DataTable dt = myclass.Selecting_DT("Customer");
}
```

There are many options really.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider re-writing your method/class with **using** statements for proper object cleanup opposed to using try..catch...

```
public class Engine
 {
    private const string _connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MY_Table;Integrated Security=True";   

    public Engine() {
    }

    public DataTable Selecting_DT(string tableName) {
        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)) {
            conn.Open();
            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [" + TableName + "]", conn)) {
                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                var dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }

        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: Good call on the `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change the connection string declaration line:

```
public string ConnictionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MY_Table;Integrated Security=True";
```

Although that is the shortest way to fix it, a recommendation is to pub it into an `app.config` file:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Engin" connectionString="ConnictionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MY_Table;Integrated Security=True";"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You can then access it in your `Engin` class:

```
private readonly string ConnictionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Engin"];
```

This will allow you to configure the database without having to rebuilding your application.

Answer (score 0):

Since the connection string is constant, you can put it in a string in your `Selecting_DT` method.
I'd add a overload of this method which can get the connection string as a parameter in case another form wants to use another connection string than the one hard coded in your class.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done like this

```
public Engin myclass = new Engin() { connictionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MY_Table;Integrated Security=True" };
```

Comment: He will still have to write it for every declaration

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest you to store connectionstring in Config file instead of hard-coding it in your code and then have a static variable for the connectionstring so its at class level instead of object level.

It will be called only once if you define it as static.

```
public static string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnectionString"];
```